# Email field data missing on subsequent email submissions to lists

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have a SharePoint 2013 On-Premise Farm with inbound email configured. The emails are coming through to lists just fine and saving the attachments as you would expect, however we've encountered what we think is a bug.

We have the following list configuration (though this happens with all lists and list types):
 - Document library configured to save attachments received via inbound email
 - Inbound email settings set to overwrite files with the same name (see below screenshot)
 - Document library configured with version history, major versions only, number of copies to retain not limited

[image: Inbound Email config]

When an attachment comes through that does not share a name with a document already in the library, the email metadata (sender, subject, header, ect.) is all provided and saved with the document as properties. However when you send an attachment with a name that is the same as that of a document already in the library (a common scenario when doing daily uploads of an evolving file), the file is overwritten as expected (we want this and configured for it as mentioned above) but the email metadata is not preserved! Whats more, it wipes out all the other properties too, but keeps the version history and bumps it up to the next number

[image: Version history example]

It would make sense for all the properties to be wiped if it treats the 'overwrite' as a new document creation, but that does not account for not capturing the email metadata as it does on the first creation, nor does it explain why it keeps the version history just like it does when its a change to the document, but does not keep the properties as it normally does when you only modify part of an item (in this case the document/file).

This is highly inconvenient as we have a workflow that needs the email metadata to perform some logic and update other properties. We don't mind running this workflow on every attachment received, even if it's a waste, but we can't because the data is not captured on subsequent uploads. We also need the item to keep its previously modified custom properties (i.e. not part of the email metadata columns or the dynamic columns liked 'modified by' etc.) when it overwrites the document portion of the item.

We would like to know if this is a known bug (googling suggests otherwise, but e may just be lacking in googlefoo) and if so how to fix it. If this is intended behavior we'd like to know what the recommended approach is for solving this problem, as the workarounds we could come up with seem inelegant and hacky.

Thanks in advance!